# How are mylist.reverse() and list.reverse(mylist) executed?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

Presumably both `mylist.reverse()` and `list.reverse(mylist)` end up executing [`reverse_slice`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/faf626b8cc6dd5c952f3fa33b09ae521388479cd/Objects/listobject.c#L1025) in `listobject.c` via [`list_reverse_impl`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/faf626b8cc6dd5c952f3fa33b09ae521388479cd/Objects/listobject.c#L2462) or [`PyList_Reverse`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/faf626b8cc6dd5c952f3fa33b09ae521388479cd/Objects/listobject.c#L2471). But how do they actually get there? What are the paths from the Python expressions to the C code in that C file? What connects them? And which of those two reverse functions (if any) do they go through?

**Update** for the bounty: Dimitris' answer (Update 2: I meant the original version, before it was expanded now) and the comments under it explain parts, but I'm still missing a few things and would like to see a comprehensive answer.

- How do the two paths from the two Python expressions converge? If I understand things correctly, disassembling and discussing the byte code and what happens to the stack, particularly `LOAD_METHOD`, would clarify this. (As somewhat done by the comments under Dimitris' answer.)
- What is the "unbound method" pushed onto the stack? Is it a "C function" (which one?) or a "Python object"?
- How can I tell that it's the `list_reverse` function in the `listobject.c.h` file? I don't think the Python interpreter is like *"let's look for a file that sounds similar and for a function that sounds similar"*. I rather suspect that the `list` type is defined somewhere and is somehow "registered" under the name "`list`", and that the `reverse` function is "registered" under the name "`reverse`" (maybe that's what the [`LIST_REVERSE_METHODDEF`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13397ee47d23fda2e8d4bef40c1df986457673d1/Objects/clinic/listobject.c.h#L221-L222) macro does?).
- I'm not interested (for this question) about stack frames, argument handling, and similar things (so maybe not much of what goes on *inside* `call_function`). Really what interests me here is what I said originally, the *path* from the Python expressions to that C code in that C file. And preferably how I can find such paths in general.

To explain my motivation: For [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60694727/12671057) I wanted to know what C code does the work when I call `list.reverse(mylist)`. I was fairly confident I had found it by browsing around and searching for the names. But I want to be more certain and generally understand the connections better.

Comment: I think they should meet up fairly quickly, since `mylist.reverse` is a bound method instance of `list.reverse`.

Comment: @kaya3 I think so, too. I have another question coming up where I actually use `list.reverse(mylist)` and it matters that it's executed from an "inside view" like asking a list to reverse itself. It made me realize I don't actually know how that happens, so that's why I ask about both forms.

Comment: There is a nice [documentation](https://hackmd.io/@xff9N3eQTLSL4Trq-6setg/ByMHBMjFe?type=view) if you really want to do it yourself to check that what internals are called and what is the flow of the functions.

Comment: I found the link above from [Exploring CPython’s Internals](https://devguide.python.org/exploring/). There are other links as well which are good reads..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PyList_Reverse` is part of the C-API, you'd call it if you were manipulating Python lists in C, it isn't used in any of the two cases.

These both go through `list_reverse_impl` (actually [`list_reverse`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/clinic/listobject.c.h#L228) which wraps `list_reverse_impl`) which is the C function that implements both `list.reverse` and `list_instance.reverse`.

Both calls are handled by [`call_function`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L4912) in `ceval`, getting there after the `CALL_METHOD` opcode generated for them is executed (`dis.dis` the statements to see it). `call_function` has gone under a good deal of changes in Python 3.8 (with the introduction of [PEP 590](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0590/)) so what happens from there on is probably too big of a subject to get into in a single question.

**Additional Questions:**

> How do the two paths from the two python expressions converge? If I understand things correctly, disassembling and discussing the byte code and what happens to the stack, particularly `LOAD_METHOD`, would clarify this.

Let's start after both expressions compile to their respective bytecode representations:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Case A, for `l.reverse()` we have:

```
1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (l)
            2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (reverse)
            4 CALL_METHOD              0
            6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Case B, for `list.reverse(l)` we have:

```
1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
            2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (reverse)
            4 LOAD_NAME                2 (l)
            6 CALL_METHOD              1
            8 RETURN_VALUE
```

We can safely ignore the `RETURN_VALUE` opcode, doesn't really matter here.

Let's focus on the individual implementations for each op code, namely, `LOAD_NAME`, `LOAD_METHOD` and `CALL_METHOD`. We can see what gets pushed onto the [value stack](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13397ee47d23fda2e8d4bef40c1df986457673d1/Python/ceval.c#L800) by viewing what [operations](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13397ee47d23fda2e8d4bef40c1df986457673d1/Python/ceval.c#L998) are called on it. (Note, it is initialized to point to the value stack located inside the frame object for each expression.)

[`LOAD_NAME`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13397ee47d23fda2e8d4bef40c1df986457673d1/Python/ceval.c#L2388):

What is performed in this case is pretty straight-forward. Given our name, `l` or `list` in each case, (each name is found in `co->co_names, a tuple that stores the names we use inside the code object) the steps are:

1. Look for the name inside `locals`. If found, go to 4.
2. Look for the name inside `globals`. If found, go to 4.
3. Look for the name inside `builtins`. If found, go to 4.
4. If found, push value denoted by the name onto the stack. Else, NameError.

In case A, the name `l` is found in the globals. In case B, it is found in the builtins. So, after the `LOAD_NAME`, the stack looks like:

Case A:   `stack_pointer -> [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Case B:   `stack_pointer -> <type list>`

[`LOAD_METHOD`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13397ee47d23fda2e8d4bef40c1df986457673d1/Python/ceval.c#L3337):

First, I should not that this opcode is generated only if an attribute access is performed (i.e `obj.attr`). You could also grab a method and call it via `a = obj.attr` and then `a()` but that would result in a `CALL_FUNCTION` opcode generated (see further down for a bit more).

After loading the name of the callable (`reverse` in both cases) we search the [object on the top of the stack](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13397ee47d23fda2e8d4bef40c1df986457673d1/Python/ceval.c#L3340) (either `[1, 2, 3, 4]` or `list`) for a method named `reverse`. This is done with [`_PyObject_GetMethod`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L1083), its documentation states:

> Return 1 if a method is found, 0 if it's a regular attribute
>      from `__dict__` or something returned by using a descriptor
>      protocol.

A method is only found in Case A, when we access the attribute (`reverse`) through an instance of the list object. In case B, the callable is returned after the descriptor protocol is invoked, so the return value is 0 (but we do of-course get the object back!).

Here we diverge on the value returned:

In Case A:

```
SET_TOP(meth);
PUSH(obj);  // self
```

We have a `SET_TOP` followed by a `PUSH`. We moved the method to the top of the stack and then we push the value again. In this case, `stack_pointer` now looks:

```
stack_pointer -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
                 <reverse method of lists>
```

In Case B we have:

```
SET_TOP(NULL);
Py_DECREF(obj);
PUSH(meth);
```

Again a `SET_TOP` followed by a `PUSH`. The reference count of `obj` (i.e `list`) is decreased because, as far as I can tell, it isn't really needed anymore. In this case, the stack now looks like so:

```
stack_pointer -> <reverse method of lists>
                 NULL
```

For case B, we have an additional `LOAD_NAME`. Following the previous steps, the stack for Case B now becomes:

```
stack_pointer -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
                 <reverse method of lists>
                 NULL
```

Pretty similar.

[`CALL_METHOD`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/13397ee47d23fda2e8d4bef40c1df986457673d1/Python/ceval.c#L3374):

This doesn't make any modifications to the stack. Both cases result in a call to `call_function` passing the thread state, the stack pointer and the number of positional arguments (`oparg`).

The only difference is in the expression used to pass the positional arguments.

For case A we need to account for the implicit `self` that should be inserted as the first positional argument. Since the op code generated for it doesn't signal that a positional argument has been passed (because none have been explicitly passed):

```
4 CALL_METHOD              0
```

we call `call_function` with `oparg + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1` to signal that one positional argument exists on the stack (`[1, 2, 3, 4`]).

In case B, where we explicitly pass the instance as a first argument, this is accounted for:

```
6 CALL_METHOD              1
```

so the call to `call_function` can immediately pass `oparg` as the value for the positional arguments.

> What is the "unbound method" pushed onto the stack? Is it a "C function" (which one?) or a "Python object"?

It is a Python object that wraps around a C function. The Python object is a method descriptor and the C function it wraps is `list_reverse`.

All built-in methods and function are implemented in C. During initialization, CPython [initializes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pylifecycle.c#L582) all builtins (see `list` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L1755)) and adds wrappers around all the [methods](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L5360). These wrappers (objects) are descriptors that are used to implement [Methods and Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods).

When a method is retrieved from a class via one of its instances, it is said to be bound to that instance. This can be seen by peeking at the `__self__` attribute assigned to it:

```
m = [1, 2, 3, 4].reverse
m()                        # use __self__ 
print(m.__self__)          # [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

This method can still be called even without the instance that qualifies it. It is bound to that instance. (NOTE: This is handled by the `CALL_FUNCTION` opcode, not the `LOAD/CALL_METHOD` ones).

An unbound method is one that is not yet bound to an instance. `list.reverse` is unbound, it is waiting to be invoked through an instance to bind to it.

Something being unbound doesn't mean that it cannot be called, `list.reverse` is called just fine if you explicitly pass the `self` argument yourself as an argument. Remember that methods are just special functions that (among other things) implicitly pass `self` as a first argument after being bound to an instance.

> How can I tell that it's the `list_reverse` function in the listobject.c.h file?

This is easy, you can see the list's methods getting initialized in [`listobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2754). `LIST_REVERSE_METHODDEF` is simply a macro that, when substituted, adds the `list_reverse` function to that list. The `tp_methods` of a list are then wrapped inside function objects as stated previously.

Things might seem complicated here because CPython uses an internal tool, [argument clinic](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/clinic.html), to automate argument handling. This kinda moves definitions around, obfuscating slightly.

Comment: Before `CALL_METHOD`, there's `LOAD_METHOD`, whose [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_METHOD) says *"This bytecode distinguishes two cases: if TOS has a method with the correct name, the bytecode pushes the unbound method and TOS. TOS will be used as the first argument (self) by CALL_METHOD when calling the unbound method. Otherwise, NULL and the object return by the attribute lookup are pushed"*.

Comment: So is `mylist.reverse()` that first case and `list.reverse(mylist)` that second case? So the first case pushes the unbound method and `mylist` onto the stack, while the second case pushes the unbound method onto the stack and the following `LOAD_NAME (mylist)` pushes `mylist` onto the stack? So at the point of `CALL_METHOD`, the stack is identical for both cases?

Comment: Slight correction after rereading that documentation and reading the handling of [`LOAD_METHOD`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6672c16b1d7f83789bf3a2016bd19edfd3568e71/Python/ceval.c#L3284) and [`CALL_METHOD`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6672c16b1d7f83789bf3a2016bd19edfd3568e71/Python/ceval.c#L3321) in `ceval.c`: I now think that at the point of `CALL_METHOD`, the stack is indeed identical for both cases, except that in the first case there's an additional `NULL` in the stack. And that both cases lead to identical `call_function` calls in lines 3343 and 3360. Is that right?

Comment: @HeapOverflow in case 1, that is `mylist.reverse()`, `self` is pushed onto the stack (see line 3304) thereby resulting in the common transformation we know that `self.method(args)` results in `method(self, args)`. This means that in the first case we have an additional value (`self`) on the stack, placed just above the function object.

Comment: Notice how in the calls to `call_function` we pass different values for `oparg` (used to locate the function object and the args in `call_function`). For `mylist.reverse` we pass `oparg+1` adjusting for the fact that we pushed the instance object `self` previously. At least that's the way I see things by a quickfirst glance.

Comment: That adjustment is exactly why I think we pass *the same* value for `oparg` to `call_function` (namely `1`). See my comments here: https://repl.it/repls/OverjoyedSeparateEmbeds

Comment: @HeapOverflow different value was a wrong way to put it. Different expression would be more appropriate.

Comment: Not sure you get notified automatically, but I added a bounty and clarified what I'd still like to see in an answer.

Comment: @HeapOverflow it doesn't, unfortunately. I've expanded to try and address your questions. If you could give me some initial feedback to see if I covered your questions, I'd be happy to receive it. I'll try and re-read later on tonight to see if I missed something.

Comment: Reading it now, looks great so far! One question already: You say `list.reverse` is a regular attribute access, but it looks like descriptor protocol to me. Because `list.reverse.__get__` exists and tells me it's `<method-wrapper '__get__' of method_descriptor object at 0x0158E438>`, and `hex(id(list.reverse))` tells me `'0x158e438'`. And the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol) says *"Define any of these methods and an object is considered a descriptor"*.