# Why is shuffling list(range(n)) slower than shuffling [0]*n?

Tags: python, performance, shuffle

Using `random.shuffle`, I noticed that shuffling `list(range(n))` takes about 25% more time than shuffling `[0] * n`. Here are times for sizes `n` from 1 million to 2 million:

[image: random.shuffle(mylist)]

Why is shuffling `list(range(n))` slower? Unlike for sorting a list (which needs to look at the objects) or copying a list (which increases reference counters inside the objects), the objects shouldn't matter here. This should just rearrange pointers inside the list.

I also tried `numpy.random.shuffle`, where shuffling `list(range(n))` is three times (!) slower than shuffling `[0] * n`:

[image: numpy.random.shuffle(mylist)]

I also tried a third way to rearrange the elements in the list, namely `list.reverse`. Which, as expected, took equally long for both lists:

[image: list.reverse(mylist)]

Just in case the shuffled order matters, I also tried `list.reverse` after shuffling the lists. Again, as expected, it took equally long for both lists, and also equally long as without that prior shuffling:

[image: list.reverse(mylist) after shuffling]

So what's the difference? Both shuffling and reversing only need to rearrange pointers inside the list, why do the objects matter for shuffling but not for reversing?

My benchmark code producing the times:

```
import random
import numpy
from timeit import repeat, timeit
from collections import defaultdict

shufflers = {
    'random.shuffle(mylist)': random.shuffle,
    'numpy.random.shuffle(mylist)': numpy.random.shuffle,
    'list.reverse(mylist)': list.reverse,
    }

creators = {
    'list(range(n))': lambda n: list(range(n)),
    '[0] * n': lambda n: [0] * n,
    }

for shuffler in shufflers:
    print(shuffler)
    for creator in creators:
        print(creator)
        times = defaultdict(list)
        for _ in range(10):
            for i in range(10, 21):
                n = i * 100_000
                mylist = creators[creator](n)
                # Uncomment next line for pre-shuffling
                # numpy.random.shuffle(mylist)
                time = timeit(lambda: shufflers[shuffler](mylist), number=1)
                times[n].append(time)
                s = '%.6f ' * len(times[n])
        # Indent next line further to see intermediate results
        print([round(min(times[n]), 9) for n in sorted(times)])
```

Comment: Perhaps the shuffling works by swapping entries, and the code checks if the values are different and doesn’t swap if they are the same? Have you tried looking at the source code of `random.shuffle`?

Comment: @barny It doesn't do that. But you can indeed find like 40% of the explanation there.

Comment: Curious what the plots look like on PyPy3...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `list.reverse`, as a `list` function, has access to the underlying pointers array. So it can indeed rearrange the pointers without looking at the objects in any way ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a36adfa6bbf5e612a4d4639124502135690899b8/Objects/listobject.c#L1027-L1039)):

```
reverse_slice(PyObject **lo, PyObject **hi)
{
    assert(lo && hi);

    --hi;
    while (lo < hi) {
        PyObject *t = *lo;
        *lo = *hi;
        *hi = t;
        ++lo;
        --hi;
    }
}
```

The `random.shuffle` and `numpy.random.shuffle` functions on the other hand only have an outsider view and go through the list's interface, which involves briefly loading the objects to swap them:

[`random.shuffle`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a36adfa6bbf5e612a4d4639124502135690899b8/Lib/random.py#L304-L318):

```
    def shuffle(self, x, random=None):
        ...
            for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
                # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
                j = randbelow(i+1)
                x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

[`numpy.random.shuffle`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/0b9b176dcef7f14f56dbd543c89e6da6c6b7b2e4/numpy/random/_generator.pyx#L4051-L4142):

```
    def shuffle(self, object x, axis=0):
          ...
                for i in reversed(range(1, n)):
                    j = random_interval(&self._bitgen, i)
                    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

So there's at least *potential* for a lot of cache misses. But let's as a test try `reverse` in Python:

```
    def my_reverse(x):
        lo = 0
        hi = len(x) - 1
        while lo < hi:
            x[lo], x[hi] = x[hi], x[lo]
            lo += 1
            hi -= 1
```

Benchmarking that:

[image]

Reversing `list(range(n))` was just as fast as reversing `[0] * n`, despite loading the objects. The reason is that Python creates the objects pretty much sequentially in memory. Here's a test with a million objects. Almost all were located 16 bytes after the previous one:

```
>>> mylist = list(range(10**6))
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> ctr = Counter(id(b) - id(a) for a, b in zip(mylist, mylist[1:]))
>>> for distance, how_often in ctr.most_common():
        print(distance, how_often)

16 996056
48 3933
-1584548240 1
-3024 1
2416 1
-2240 1
2832 1
-304 1
-96 1
-45005904 1
6160432 1
38862896 1
```

So no wonder it's fast, as that's very cache-friendly.

But now let's use our Python reversal on a *shuffled* list (like in the question with `list.reverse`, where it didn't make a difference):

[image]

Big difference, now that `my_reverse` loads objects from randomly all over the place, which is the opposite of cache-friendly.

And of course that's what happens with the `shuffle` functions as well. While `list(range(n))` initially is cache-friendly, the shuffling picks random indices `j` to swap with, which is very cache-unfriendly. And while `i` just moves sequentially, it's going to encounter a lot of already randomly swapped objects, so that's cache-unfriendly as well.

Answer (score 5):

*(note: I didn't have time to finish this answer, so here's a start -- this definitely doesn't fit in a comment, hopefully it can help someone else finish this out!)*

---

this appears to be due to locality of reference (and perhaps a cpython implementation detail -- I don't see the same results in pypy for example)

a few data points before an attempt at explanation:

[`random.shuffle`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61ac612e78e4f2625977406fb6f366e0a644673a/Lib/random.py#L304-L324) is implemented in pure python and works for any mutable sequence type -- it is not specialized for lists.

- this means that every swap involves `__getitem__`, increasing the refcount of the item, `__setitem__`, decreasing the refcount of the item

[`list.reverse`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61ac612e78e4f2625977406fb6f366e0a644673a/Objects/listobject.c#L1023-L1037) is implemented in C and only works for `list` (using implementation details of a list)

- this means that every swap happens without invoking `__getitem__` or changing reference counts.  the internal items of the list are rearranged directly

**the important bit being the *reference counts***

in cpython, [the reference count is stored with the object itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/61ac612e78e4f2625977406fb6f366e0a644673a/Include/object.h#L105-L109), and nearly all objects are stored in the heap.  in order to adjust the reference count (even temporarily) a write to the `ob_refcnt` will page in the `PyObject` structure into cache/memory/etc.

(here's where I ran out of time -- I would probably do some memory fault analysis to confirm this hypothesis)

Comment: I added my own answer now, but I'd still be interested in that memory fault analysis you mentioned and would gladly accept your answer if you could provide that. I tried it myself, learned about `perf` [from Victor Stinner](https://vstinner.github.io/analysis-python-performance-issue.html#statistics-on-the-cpu-l1-instruction-cache), but then on the machine where I tried it, it didn't offer cache statistics :-(